# How to autofill auth form based on web site counterpart

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

When authenticating in mobile apps like Facebook, after having authenticated in their web site (fb.com), the mobile app would suggest us to autofill that same auth information.

How do we achieve this continuity in Cordova apps? How do we signal the OS that the mobile app is an honest extension of the web site? How is it done in native apps?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @E.Maggini I wouldn't know where to begin with. I have a properly marked up Log In form, but that's not enough as the OS has no way of knowing that the given app is connected to a website.